# Consumer stop messages consuming from specific topic after some time of running

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

Environment Information

docker image based on node:12.13.1-alpine

Node Version : 12.13.1

node-rdkafka version : latest

The below code snippet is working fine. But sometimes it's stopping reading messages from specific Kafka's partition (we are having about 20 topics (5 partitions each one) with same pattern). We are not getting any errors. After service restart and rebalance consuming continue as usual. Which tuning should be done to manage those stuck partitions?

Throughput is low, it's about 150 messages for all topics per minute, each message is small JSON with some details (~500kb). We are running with 10 pods for specific service.

```
import { ConsumerStream, createReadStream } from 'node-rdkafka';

const kafkaConsumer = createConsumerStream(shutdown, config.kafka.topics);
  kafkaConsumer.on('data', async (rawMessage) => {
    const {
      topic, partition, offset, value
    } = rawMessage;

    try {
      await processKafkaMessage(rawMessage);
      kafkaConsumer.consumer.commit({
        topic: topic,
        partition: partition,
        offset: offset + 1
      });
    } catch (err) {
      logger.error('Failed to process inbound kafka message');
    }
  });


export const createConsumerStream = (shutdown, topics:Array<string>):ConsumerStream => {
  
  const globalConfig = {
    'metadata.broker.list': ['kafka:9092'],
    'group.id': 'my_group_1',
    'enable.auto.commit': false,
    'partition.assignment.strategy': 'roundrobin',
    'topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms': 30 * 100,
    'batch.num.messages':  100000,
    'queued.max.messages.kbytes':  10000,
    'fetch.message.max.bytes': 10000,
    'fetch.max.bytes': 524288000,
    'retry.backoff.ms':  200,
    retries: 5
  };

  const topicConfig = { 'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest' };

  const streamOptions = {
    topics: topics,
    waitInterval: batchMaxTime,
    fetchSize: batchMaxSize
  };

  const stream:ConsumerStream = createReadStream(globalConfig, topicConfig, streamOptions);
  
  stream.on('error', (err) => {
    logger.error('Error in kafka consumer stream', {
      error_msg: err.message,
      error_name: err.name
    });
  });

  stream.consumer.on('event.error', (err) => {
    if (err.stack === 'Error: Local: Broker transport failure') return;

    logger.error('Error in kafka consumer');

    stream.emit('rd-kafka-error', err);
  });

  stream.consumer.on('rebalance', ({ message }, assignment) => {
    logger.info('Rebalance event', { assigned_topics: assignment });
  });
```

Comment: `metadata.broker.list` doesn't take a regex... But, If the consumer has zero lag, then it'll stop reading. How are you verifying its stuck?

Comment: I see in minion metrics lags for specific partition (1-2 messages for more than an hour.) After rebalance messages are consumed

Comment: Regex does not matter here, issue is in consumption

Comment: Well, if you give the wrong brokers list, it should fail to consume. Like I said, I don't think regex is valid there. It seems that you're trying to subscribe to _topics_ by regex, which is not the broker list

Comment: My bad, wrong copy paste. Brokers list is not regex. Fixed that in code sample. But still, the issue is not here. Pay attention to description please. "Consumer stop messages consuming from specific topic after some time of running". It's a random topic/partition/random time

Comment: Thank you. I understand the question, but I was trying to get you to create a [mcve]. I don't have any suggestions why certain partitions would not be consumed. Perhaps your few `max.bytes` settings are too small for data in those partitions? Maybe you can try forcing a new leader partition for the topics? Or does restarting the brokers change anything?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried to change ```fetch.max.bytes``` without any success. Didn't try to restart brokers, but this cluster works with additional services and there is no such errors there. What do yo mean in " forcing a new leader partition"

Comment: Assuming there multiple replicas of each partition, only one of those gets read by your client. Maybe that specific broker is the problem. `kafka-topics --describe` output will show those values. You can manually reassign them with a cli tool. The first broker ID in the partitions array should become the leader https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-tools-kafka-leader-election.html

Comment: Ok, thanks, will investigate it.